# ¿Cómo podría eliminar array idénticos que están dentro de un array general?

Tags: javascript

Estoy "generando" unos `array` que unos se me repiten `n` cantidad, entonces quería saber si es mas fácil poder eliminar los `array` idénticos o si existe otra forma de como evitar que pase eso, en caso de ser posible y ser mas fácil (eliminar), agradecería me aclaren un poco el panorama de como podría solucionar este asunto.

lo que tengo es algo como esto:

```
var elementos = [ [1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [4,2,3,5] ];
```

> un `array` que contiene otros `array` que pueden ser de distinto tamaño.

entonces el objetivo es que los `array`que son exactamente iguales , se eliminen y tener algo asi:

```
var elementos = [ [1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], [4,2,3,5] ];
```

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar loops anidados, puedes usar un objeto que actué como diccionario(clave/valor).

Se convierte el array a string con `JSON.stringify(arr)` y este valor se setea como clave y el array como valor. Y en cada iteración se comprueba si existe dicha clave en el objeto si es así quiere decir que es un elemento repetido.

Te he puesto los dos ejemplos, el primero con el `for-loop` convencional y el otro con método `filter`.

Es una solución simple espero que te sirva y este algoritmo es conocido como [frequency counter pattern](https://medium.com/@hyoeun93/frequency-counter-pattern-c9e0aeb1d922). Te dejo el link para más info.

```js
const elementos = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [0, 1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 2, 3, 5]
];

const map = {}
const unique = [];

// con for-loop convencional
for (let i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
  // se convierte el elemento en string
  const key = JSON.stringify(elementos[i]);
  // se comprueba que no exista en el objeto
  if (!map[key]) {
    // se añade en el elemento en el array unique que
    // contiene los elementos no repetidos
    unique.push(elementos[i]);
    // se setea como clave este elemento para validar
    // que no sea repetido en las iteraciones posteriores
    map[key] = elementos[i];
  }
}

// Con el método array
const map2 = {};
const unique2 = elementos.filter((elem) => {
  const key = JSON.stringify(elem);
  if (!map2[key]) {
    map2[key] = elem;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});

console.log(unique);
console.log(unique2);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si me sirve tu respuesta. y gracias por el link de la info.